# How do I list all servers & list the accounts/users that use the services?

Tags: list, powershell, server

I'm new to powershell and I barely understand it. Recently I was given a task to list all the servers we use as well as list the accounts that use the services, then also to run it monthly. I've found many scripts that list the servers but none that combine both the server and account. I think maybe I can use pipe and combine the two but I'm not sure. I need help.

Comment: You can grab the service info from `Win32_Service` via `Get-CimInstance`. But beneath that: Do you have any code to start with?

Comment: Start bit by bit. Can you see a server? Can you see a service? Can you see an account? As you start to understand all the pieces you will be able to eventually combine them.